# Emmet plugin in Visual Studio screws up ordinary indentation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, emmet

It's beyond me how anyone can use the Emmet plugin in Visual Studio without instantly getting dead frustrated by the fact that ordinary indentation doesn't work anymore.

If I try to indent a line it just jumps over the line and puts the cursor further down the html structure without indenting my line.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem goes away if I restart VS. Then under certain (mysterious) circumstances it comes back. So it's simply a bug that occurs now and then.

I tried to consequently reproduce it, but after quite some testing I still didn't succeed to find what's causing it.